# echo of variables does not work

Tags: php, sql

Hey guys i have written a short piece of code which connects to a database and then puts some data out with `echo` but it doesn't work like I want: Edit Updated Code:

```
   <html>
 <head>
  <title>Automatische E-mails</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <?php
    include("db_login.php");

    $link = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass) or die ("Keine Verbindung zu der Datenbank moeglich.");
    mysql_select_db($db, $link);
    $sql = "SELECT `ID_Zuordnung`, `Username`, `Hostname_alt`, `Datum_Ausgabe` FROM `zuordnung` WHERE `Status_Tausch` = 'OK' AND `Status_Altgeraet` = 'NOK' ORDER BY `Hostname_alt` ASC";

    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    while($resultarray = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
            echo '<p>'.$resultarray['HW_Typ'].'</p>';
            echo '<p>'.$resultarray['Hostname_alt'].'</p>';
            echo '<p>'.$resultarray['Username'].'</p>';
            echo '<p>'.$resultarray['Emailadresse'].'</p>';
            echo '<p>'.$resultarray['Datum_Ausgabe'].'</p>';
            echo '<p>'.$resultarray['Abteilung'].'</p>';
    }

    ?> 
 </body>
</html>
```

Running produced this output:

```
'.$resultarray['HW_Typ'].'

'; echo '

'.$resultarray['Hostname_alt'].'
'; echo '

'.$resultarray['Username'].'
'; echo '

'.$resultarray['Emailadresse'].'
'; echo '

'.$resultarray['Datum_Ausgabe'].'
'; echo '

'.$resultarray['Abteilung'].'
'; } ?>
```

I don't get where is my error is because yesterday everything worked!

Comment: remove the bracket after echo?

Comment: Try to echo without use of parentheses, like this: echo '<p>'.$resultarray['Hostname_alt'].'</p>';

Comment: Please stop using `mysql_*` functions

Comment: I doubt it causes the problem you are seeing, but the sql query has a mismatched parenthesis at `ON users.Username = zuordnung.Username)`

Comment: mysqli does work, but it doesn't solve your problem. What TWCrap and Bondye are trying to say: use of the mysql_ functions is discouraged, "use PDO or MySQLi instead" (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)

Comment: @Alesfatalis, mysql_* is deprecrated. So in the near futer, it isn't there anymore. So it's the best if you use mysqli_* now, so you don't have to switch then...

Comment: @TWCrap its an internal site so there would be no problem

Comment: @Alesfatalis, if you never update the engine of PHP, there is indeed no problem... but if you keep PHP updated, it is an problem...

Comment: @TWCrap i dont think someone will upgrade it because here are a lot more php sites which no one will update but i still need to solve my problem the funny thing is yesterday everything worked

Comment: @Alesfatalis, it's your site, so it's your call. But for public site's, i shouldn't recommend it...

Comment: @TWCrap thanks will use mysqli when im going to make a public site

Comment: @Alesfatalis, i will make an answer, with possible solutions...

Comment: @TWCrap thanks for helping i will try you're solutions

Comment: @Alesfatalis, i've posted an answer... (sorry for my bad english if it is so)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are an couple of things that i see that may cause the problem:

**1:**

1.1:The query. You have an ) but nowhere an ( SO that one can be removed... Also you had an ; at the end. Must not harm it, but not neccesary

1.2 And your missing an , after Zuordnung_ID

1.3 And by the order are you missing how the order will be (ASC or DESC)

1.4 And an another note (not needed as far as i know, but it is teached it to myself that way, is that fieldnames must be surrounded by an `

So the sql code will then looks like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT `Zuordnung_ID`, `HW_Typ`, `Hostname_alt`, `Username`, `Emailadresse`, `Datum_Ausgabe`, `Abteilung`
        FROM `zuordnung`
            ON `users.Username` = `zuordnung.Username`
        WHERE `Status_Tausch`='OK' AND `Status_Altgeraet`='NOK'
        ORDER BY `Hostname_alt` ASC";
```

**2:**

echo doesn't need (), and try to use the same quotes at the begin and and. So than it will look like this:

```
while($resultarray = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
            echo '<p>'.$resultarray['HW_Typ'].'</p>';
            echo '<p>'.$resultarray['Hostname_alt'].'</p>';
            echo '<p>'.$resultarray['Username'].'</p>';
            echo '<p>'.$resultarray['Emailadresse'].'</p>';
            echo '<p>'.$resultarray['Datum_Ausgabe'].'</p>';
            echo '<p>'.$resultarray['Abteilung'].'</p>';
    }
```

You should try this

**Version 2:**
Try this:

```
$textHolder = "";
while($resultarray = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
            $textHolder .= '<p>' . $resultarray['HW_Typ'] . '</p>';
            $textHolder .= '<p>' . $resultarray['Hostname_alt'] . '</p>';
            $textHolder .= '<p>' . $resultarray['Username'] . '</p>';
            $textHolder .= '<p>' . $resultarray['Emailadresse'] . '</p>';
            $textHolder .= '<p>' . $resultarray['Datum_Ausgabe'] . '</p>';
            $textHolder .= '<p>' . $resultarray['Abteilung'] . '</p>';
    }
echo $textHolder;
```

If version 2 don't work, try version 3

**Version 3:**

What you can try, is what i use to parse data from an database. mysql_fetch_assoc. So then the code will look something like this:

```
$textHolder = "";
while($resultassoc = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
            $textHolder .= '<p>' . $resultassoc['HW_Typ'] . '</p>';
            $textHolder .= '<p>' . $resultassoc['Hostname_alt'] . '</p>';
            $textHolder .= '<p>' . $resultassoc['Username'] . '</p>';
            $textHolder .= '<p>' . $resultassoc['Emailadresse'] . '</p>';
            $textHolder .= '<p>' . $resultassoc['Datum_Ausgabe'] . '</p>';
            $textHolder .= '<p>' . $resultassoc['Abteilung'] . '</p>';
    }
echo $textHolder;
```

Comment: ok updated my code in my first post there must be still an error did i everything wright? The sql query is wright i tested it in phpmyadmin

Comment: nope none of them its annoying there are no points why it shouldn't work but its still hapening the same shit :(

Comment: @Alesfatalis,  what if you don't echo $textHolder? so it only adds the values to $textHolder, but doesn't output it...

Comment: i have copied the whole php code in an hello world sample from the i-net and now everything works you get the wright answer because you fixed lot of other issues. Thanks :)

Comment: @Alesfatalis, glad i could help :D Hope you have learned from this ^_^

Answer (score 0):

use

```
        echo "<p>$resultarray['HW_Typ']</p>";
        echo "<p>$resultarray['Hostname_alt']</p>";
        echo "<p>$resultarray['Username']</p>";
        echo "<p>$resultarray['Emailadresse']</p>";
        echo "<p>$resultarray['Datum_Ausgabe']</p>";
        echo "<p>$resultarray['Abteilung']</p>";
```

will work

Comment: What is different in this ? `echo` can be `echo()`

Comment: This won't work.  The `$resultarray[...]` inside quotes will not parse as intended.  It needs `{$resultarray[...']}` to work.

Comment: sorry i did not noticed the  `)`

Answer (score 0):

Either the code was not copied here correctly, or there is a mismatched single quote `'` in `db_login.php`.  Check that very carefully.

Comment: db_login.php is correct it is used by 2 sites already. The code is copied with strl + a so it should be correct

Answer (score 0):

Your Sql query seems to have errors. May be you missed a comma between the first 2 columns(Zuordnung_ID, HW_Typ) and the query uses an ON join condition, but there is no JOIN with the users table.

make sure your query is correct or may be the following query correct?

```
SELECT Zuordnung_ID, HW_Typ, Hostname_alt, Username, Emailadresse, Datum_Ausgabe, Abteilung
FROM zuordnung
    INNER JOIN users ON users.Username = zuordnung.Username)
WHERE Status_Tausch='OK' AND Status_Altgeraet='NOK'
ORDER BY Hostname_alt
```

Comment: While the sql query has at least one syntax error, that does not explain why the output occurs as posted.

Answer (score 0):

That actually just looks like your webserver does not have PHP enabled, and is serving you the raw source file. I bet if you view the source you will see the whole PHP source.

Comment: yeah is see the whole source but php is enable im in the same folder where already a php site is running

Comment: can you imagine any configuration which can cause this?

Comment: no clue to be honest; but at least you can simplify your example script to a single echo